# My program compiles but still shows an error, java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, file-processing

```
public static void cCommand(Scanner in) throws FileNotFoundException {   

      System.out.println();      

      System.out.print("Type an output file name: "); 
      String outFile = in.nextLine();
      
      PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new File("out.txt"));
      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("story.txt"));   
      
      while (input.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = input.nextLine();
         Scanner console = new Scanner(line);
         while (input.hasNext()) { 
            String word = console.next();
            if (word.startsWith("<") && word.endsWith(">")) { 
               char first = word.charAt(1);
               String a = aeiou(first);
               word = word.replace("<"," ");
               word = word.replace(">"," ");
               word = word.replace("-"," ");
               System.out.print("Please type" + a + word + ": ");
               String replace = in.next();
               ps.print(" " + replace);
            } else {
               ps.print(" " + word);
            }
         }
      }
      
   } //end of cCommand method
```

this error pops up:

```
Type an output file name: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: post the complete error and how are you calling this function?

Comment: Why you checking one scanner `while (input.hasNext())` and then querying another `String word = console.next();`?

Comment: What is `aeiou(first)`? Do you have a `aeiou(char c)` method?

Comment: Type an output file name: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
 at CJMadLibs.cCommand(CJMadLibs.java:61)
 at CJMadLibs.commandPrompt(CJMadLibs.java:32)
 at CJMadLibs.main(CJMadLibs.java:15)                                                                       @deadshot this is the full error, I am calling this method in another method, inside an if/else loop. The method call is cCommand(in).

Comment: @robinhoodjr yes, there is another method called aeiou(char c).

Comment: Since i am looking at a .txt file, its just a bunch of sentences. So what I am doing here is looking at each line, so loops at each line, then at each line, i look at each word.  @talex

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchElementException` error is because either

`String replace = in.next();`

or

`String word = console.next();`

still calling `next` but one of them no longer has a next element to provide. Make sure to call `hasNext()` first before calling `next()`.

Comment: I dont get how the String replace = in.next(); is an error, am I not just creating a string where the user types in something? Also, Im pretty sure my while loop already calls the hasNext() method. correct me if im wrong, but im still unsure what the problem is here.

Comment: Yes, your loop has already calls `hasNext()` but it only for `Scanner input` variable. While the `Scanner console` and `String replace = in.next();` don't have the `hasNext()` safeguard. Unless you show update your question with the file and whatever comes in `Scanner in`, I can't trace it.

Comment: Try to match every `hasNext()/hasNextLine()` with the safeguard `next()/nextLine()`, it should have been equal.